# MyBatis: can I map two result columns into single object property?

Tags: java, persistence, mybatis

I have a case where I have a table that stores a geo-location across two columns, 'latitude' and 'longitude'. When I map my result set to a Java object, I want to group these two columns together and return them as a nested object, but this nested object is not some association (via a foreign key) to another table.

So, imagine this query:

```
SELECT id, name, latitude, longitude 
FROM places
WHERE id = <some_id>
```

And, I want to map that - ideally using a `resultMap` in my XML file - to this:

```
public class Place {
   private Long id;
   private String name;
   private GeoPoint point;
   
   public Place(Long id, String name, GeoPoint point) {
      this.id = id;
      this.name = name;
      this.point = point;
   }
   ...
}

public class GeoPoint {
   private BigDecimal latitude;
   private BigDecimal longitude;
   
   public Place(BigDecimal latitude, BigDecimal longitude) {
      this.latitude = latitude;
      this.longitude = longitude;
   }
   ...
}
```

From what I've read of the documentation, it's not clear whether this is actually possible to achieve in a MyBatis `resultMap`. The only discussion on nested objects is when those objects are formed from columns returned as part of a join to another table (`association` or `collection`) - i.e. there appears to be a need for an ID.

In my case, these columns merely form a nested value object and do not have a unique ID of their own.

Could anyone share a solution to my problem that avoids me having to return `HashMap<String, String>` from my mapper rather than a fully constructed object?

Comment: association in mybatis is not bound to any join clause. You can set the column property of your result (or arg in this case) element to a field in a single table select.

Comment: Thanks, will try that

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following result maps:

```xml
<select id="selectPlace" parameterType="long" resultMap="placeResultMap">
    SELECT id, name, latitude, longitude FROM places WHERE id = #{parameter};
</select>

<resultMap id="placeResultMap" type="com.xyz.entity.Place">
    <constructor>
        <idArg column="id" javaType="Long"/>
        <arg column="name" javaType="String"/>
        <arg resultMap="pointResultMap" javaType="com.xyz.entity.GeoPoint"/>
    </constructor>
</resultMap>

<resultMap id="pointResultMap" type="com.xyz.entity.GeoPoint">
    <constructor>
        <arg column="latitude" javaType="BigDecimal"/>
        <arg column="longitude" javaType="BigDecimal"/>
    </constructor>
</resultMap>
```